# Set the zoom level for the html file generated using PHPExcel?

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

I am trying to generate a HTML file using PHPExcel. I have more than 30 columns and would like to zoom the page.

I've tried using the code below, but hasn't worked.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setFitToPage(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setFitToWidth(2);
```

I've also tried using this, but hasn't worked either.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getSheetView()->setZoomScale(250);
```

Both options don't work in the case of HTML page, but the zoom works if it is an Excel file. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may see from the chaining of commands, the `setZoomScale()` method is part of the `Worksheet` class and it will only have an impact in case a worksheet is written, not when it is read.

The PHPDoc for PHPExcel lists the internal command [`_writeSheetViews()`](http://www.osakac.ac.jp/labs/koeda/tmp/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007/PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007_Worksheet.html) for Excel2007 writer and [`_storeZoom`](http://www.osakac.ac.jp/labs/koeda/tmp/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5/PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5_Worksheet.html#method_storeZoom) for old Excel versions whereas [`PHPExcel_Writer_HTML`](http://www.osakac.ac.jp/labs/koeda/tmp/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Writer/PHPExcel_Writer_HTML.html) doesn't offer similar behavior.

What you may try is adding custom CSS styling to the created HTML file that may use smaller font-sizes for the table. AFAIK you won't be able to change the zoom level of the browser programmatically.